# Perl GUI script that should work with the application minimzed. How make it stay that way? Focus related problem

Tags: perl, winapi, user-interface, automation

I'm trying to develop a Perl script that controls an application in a very simple manner(fills some boxes, presses some keys). 
I've implemented everything using Win32::GuiTest.
The goal is to make it work with the app being minimized in tray, allowing me to use the PC at the same time.

I'm using functions like: WMSetText , SelComboItem , SendMessage, PushChildButton.

All of them work fine, except for PushChildButton. Whenever this function is called, I'm losing focus(even though the controlled app stays minimized) from whatever I'm doing.

Application that I'm using before calling PushChildButton: http: // i. imgur.com/7B5kj.png

Application that I'm using after calling PushChildButton:  http: // i. imgur.com/VCskW.png

I've tried killing the focus like this, but it did not work:

```
my $msg_id=0x08; 
SendMessage( @_[ 0 ], $msg_id, @_[ 1 ], undef ); 

@_[ 0 ] - handle to the application

@_[ 1 ] -handle to the "Edit Control" that I think* that takes the focus after pressing the button
```

*Let me elaborate this a bit. The application still stays minimized, but sometimes that "Edit Control" resource contains strings that are concatenated with the keys that I've pressed while losing the focus.

PS: I'm a beginner with Perl and WinAPI(in fact this is my first project), so I might 
have explained things a bit unclear. Please ask me everything that you feel that I 
should elaborate.

Comment: I've checked the application source code, and it seems that it uses GetFocus() and SetFocus(). I could as well, try to implement those to functions in my script, in order to revert the focus back, but I have some doubts. Will this focus switch be fast enough so that there won't be any keyboard leaks?                                                               LE: Yes, I have the application source code(it's an open source app) but I don't want to modify it and recompile it, because new versions are launched once in a while.

Answer (score 0):

1. Most likely this is a windows problem, not perl. 
   People do this normally with a normal window moved outside 
   the visible desktop range, e.g. to the left, x=-600.
2. Use Win32::GUI instead. This will save you many more headaches.

Comment: IMHO, Win32::GUI is used to create a GUI for a Perl application. What I'm trying to do is to control a commercial application with a script that I wrote. The commercial app still stays minimized when I use PushChildButton, but it takes the Focus from what I'm doing at that moment. Most likely it is programmed to do that and I need to find a way to cancel this side effect.

Comment: I see. So you have to workaround the client event. You need to manually set the focus either directly after the PushChildButton call, or after some timeout.

Comment: How would you do it? I tried like this using WM_KILLFOCUS(0x08)as I posted above and it did not work.